# Why Pocket API always returns 401?

Tags: python

I'm trying the following code:

```
import requests
auth_params = {'consumer_key': '77081-4664470ecdeaa9c127925c30', 'redirect_uri': 'https://weibo.com/u/5069317986/home?topnav=1&wvr=6'}
tkn = requests.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request', data = auth_params)
tkn.content

usr_params = {'consumer_key': '77081-4664470ecdeaa9c127925c30', 'code': '21ff0ee0-2b65-fe35-f4b3-a18ed3'}
usr = requests.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/authorize', data = usr_params)
usr.content
```

And then:

```
yes_params = {'consumer_key': '77081-4664470ecdeaa9c127925c30', 'access_token': 'f12deb4e-8ead-9f98-430c-baaee7&username=jelly.wxt%40gmail.com', 'tag':'y'}
yes_result = requests.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/get', data = yes_params)
yes_result.text
```

But it returns a 401.How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 401 status typically means that the authentication failed.

Looking at the [examples in pocket api documentation](https://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/retrieve), it seems that you should not include `&username=jelly.wxt%40gmail.com` in the access token.

```
yes_params = {
  'consumer_key': '77081-4664470ecdeaa9c127925c30', 
  'access_token': 'f12deb4e-8ead-9f98-430c-baaee7', 
  'tag':'y'
}
yes_result = requests.post('https://getpocket.com/v3/get', data = yes_params)
yes_result.text
```